# How to add custom project templates to VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, configuration

There is a tool to export project as template in vs, however ho do I use that zip file, what was created by this tool?

Answer (score 0):

Just double click the file and follow the prompts to install the template. Once done, you *may* need to restart your IDE.

After that, when you say `File -> New Project` you should see you new Project Template listed.